# Reactjs/Redux - Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am making a shopping cart - onClick I have redux adding items to cartItems array.

In the code below (**increment reducer** its the last one after add/remove) I am trying to get rid of duplicate values from the cartItems array which holds all the items added to the shopping cart, and display a total number of unique items in the cart with cartIcon: {value: 0} - which is by default 0 (before adding any items).

```
const initialState = {
    cartItems: [],
    cartQuantity: 0,
    cartIcon: {value: 0},
}


export const addToCartSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'cart',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        
        add(state, action ) {

            const itemIndex = state.cartItems.findIndex(
                (props) => props.id === action.payload.id
                );
                if(itemIndex >= 0){
                    state.cartItems[itemIndex].cartQuantity += 1;
                } else {
                    const tempProduct = {...action.payload, cartQuantity: 1}
                    state.cartItems.push(tempProduct);

                }

            
        },
        remove(state, action) {
            const removeItem = state.cartItems.filter(
                (cartItem) => cartItem.id !== action.payload.id 
            
            );
            state.cartItems = removeItem;
        },


        increment: (state) => {
            const Items = state.cartItems.filter(
                (element, index) => state.cartItems.indexOf(element) === index);
                state.value = Items.length;
        }      // if i just do state.value += 1
               // then the value goes up by 1
               // but I want to display the amount of unique entries

    },

});
```

Here onClick I am pulling data from the item that was "added" to the cart and additionally trying to increment the cartIcon number by 1 (if the item hasn't been yet added to the array cartItems). **The problem could be here? Because the error mentions all the props and data I'm pulling to be rendered into the cart.**

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const handleAddToCart = (props) => {
  dispatch(add(props));
};

  return (<>
                <div id={props.id} className='shopitem'>
                    <img src={props.url} />
                    <h2>{props.title}</h2>
                    <p className='boldprice'>${props.price}</p>
                    <button onClick={() => {
                    handleAddToCart(props);
                    dispatch(increment())
                  }}> ADD TO CART </button>
                </div>
        </>
  )
}
```

And here I am trying to display the amount of unique items to the shopping cart icon.

```
const count = useSelector((state) => state.cart.cartIcon.value)
{count}
```

For some reason I am getting this error. If I just do `state.value += 1` it will add +1 to the shopping cart icon, however I only want to display +1 for each unique item.

**"Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, title, price, url, cartQuantity}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."**

Please help - I am relatively new to Javascript and programming overall.. I may be making a stupid mistake, so if something is clearly wrong.. then please let me know :)

Comment: Can you console.log(count) to see if it's an object or a number?

Comment: yes its a number - 0

Comment: ok forget it - I got it figured out but if u want I will give you an upvote if u leave a reply...  because doing some console.logging helped me fix the problem ! so you indirectly helped me :) @Hayyaun

Comment: Why are your reducers mutating state instead of creating a new copy?

Comment: @morganney it's probably because I'm a newbie and that's the only way I was able to figure out the functionality :(

Comment: Gotcha, try looking over these docs https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: @morganney oh snap thats super interesting, thank u as well ++